# Chart.js show date on X axis ticks, but only when day is different from previous tick

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to build a line-chart with a time-scale using Chart.js (version 4.2.1).

On that scale, I let Chart.js resolve the ticks to show.

This is all working fine, but now I want to improve the usability of this chart by showing the actual date of a tick. This information should only be shown if the tick is on a different day than the previous tick

For instance:
[Example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6pbu.png)

In this sample, the X axis displays only the hour-portion of the tick, which makes it hard(er) for the user to understand on what day a tick occurs. Adding the full date to every tick will make the chart too crowded.

In an attempt to make it more clear what I want to achieve: instead of rendering the X axis ticks as:

```
----------------------------------------------------
5:00   15:00   01:00   15:00   11:00   21:00   07:00
```

I would like to render them as:

```
----------------------------------------------------
5:00   15:00   01:00   15:00   11:00   21:00   07:00
Jan 1          Jan 2.          Jan 3           Jan 4
```

I tried changing the displayFormats of the time scale, but that changes the format for all ticks. I just want to change the ticks when a new date starts on the scale.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use ticks.callback as shown [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats).

For example:

```
      var last_date = ''; // global var outside config

      // Within config.scales.x.ticks add this callback:

      callback: function(val, index, ticks) {
        // Get value of tick (already formatted by time axis option)
        tick = this.getLabelForValue(val);

        // Extract parts of tick using regex 
        date = tick.match(/[a-z]+ \d+/i)[0];
        time = tick.match(/\d+:\d+/i)[0];
        ampm = tick.match(/[a-z]\.[a-z]\./i)[0];
        
        
        if (last_date !== date) {   // Show Date
           last_date = date
           return date + " " + time + " " + ampm
        } else {                    // Don't show
           return time + " " + ampm
        }
       }
```